# How to configure Action Group on Azure Monitor Alert to use compilable (C# or F#) Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts

I was trying to figure out how to configure [Action Group to use Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/action-groups#function). Documentation says that:

> Calls an existing HTTP trigger endpoint in Azure Functions.
>
> You may have a limited number of Function actions in an Action Group.

So what I tried already:

- C# script file created on the portal - **works**
- Powershell script created on the portal - **works**
- Powershell script deployed to Azure Function - **works**
- compiled Function App in C# deployed to Azure Function - **doesn't work**
- compiled Function App in F# deployed to Azure Function - **doesn't work**

My preference is actually to use F# here and this is the reason why I'm trying to figure out (I know that I can use fsx and then it probably goes fine, however I want use compiled app and if it is not possible know why)

Each app I tested calling and endpoint from postman and each time it was fine. I tried also Function and Anonymous AuthorizationLevel.

And by saying that action doesn't work I mean following:

- no evidence of calling that function (on Azure Function or App Insights)
- no error or warning regardless the side

I also tried to configure a Webhook action by putting Azure Function endpoint but it also doesn't work. Did you understand why it is happening like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out that and the issue was that in compilable version I didn't handle `post` verb. After adding it, all works as expected.